# Visual Studio keeps requesting missing web components

Tags: visual-studio-2010

When I open a particular mvc 3 website project in VS 2010 I get the following message:

The Web Project "X" requires missing web components to run with Visual Studio. Would you like to download and install them using the Web Platform Installer now?
ASP.NET Web pages with Razor syntax.

When I click yes

The web platform installer shows with the message that "0" items need to be installed.

My other mvc 3 projects do not show this behavior

Not a major inconvenience, but still...

thoughts any one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C.,

That shouldn't happen, and it would be interesting to figure out why.  In the meantime, you should be able to turn this off by unchecking the "Package Restore" checkbox in Visual Studio's Options dialog.  (Select "Package Manager" in the tree view to find it.)

If it's happening only for specific projects, you can solve this more surgically by removing the packages.config file for the affected project.  In fact, if you want to do root cause analysis, you should look into why that file exists and how it got there.

HTH,
Clay

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, the do not work. I removed the package file, switched of package options, cleared the cache etc. 
It must be related to the project file of a single web-project, if I start a new mvc 3 razor project, it doesn't show the dialog.

Answer (score 4):

I got the same error after reinstalling my computer.

I came to this conclusion, VS needs IISExpress to load my additional project. The addition projects has a webservice and it can run locally. Even if my endpoints points to a local address it still needs the IISExpress (standard IIS 7.5 does not respond the endpoint request) to open from VS (im running VS2010).

So after installing IISExpress i could reload my project in VS.

Comment: Thanks for sharing! It looks like that there are more than one reason for VS to pop the missing stuff question. In my case it worked for new projects, just not a specific old one...